# How many threads does a .NET web application natively use?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, multithreading, iis

This has been bugging me for a while.  Assuming that I am not using any explicit form of task parallelism (e.g. `Paralell.ForEach`), how many threads are natively used when I deploy a web application to a Windows Server?

In other words, if the web server has an eight-core processor, does the application only use one of those cores if I am not explicitly telling it to use more?

I'll bet I have missed something simple here, so flame on--but I still want to know the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: It depends on the type of ASP.NET application. we need more details about the application that is deployed.

Comment: Let's say an ASP.NET MVC application with a few WebAPI endpoints which each point to a method in a Business Logic Layer.  The BLL probably references an entity class and runs your typical querys and cruds.  Does that help?  Thanks!

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt hosted in what container?  IIS?  If so, IIS is a fully featured web server and will use all the cores available.

Comment: Yes, IIS.  I think your question is reflective of the part I am not getting: if IIS is smart enough to use all cores, then why would I ever need to explicitly use things like `Parallel.ForEach`?  Thanks!

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt, IIS will ensure that each of your requests will be distributed across threads/cores efficiently.  However, an individual request runs on a single thread.  If, for example, in order to satisfy a request you need to invoke five separate external REST apis on five different servers, it would be silly to do that sequentially.  Using threads would allow you to parallelize those five tasks so that the total time elapsed is minimized.  In truth, usually doing all the work on the request thread (via `await`, etc.) is sufficient.  But sometimes you need to optimize.

Comment: Thank you @KirkWoll, that was very instructive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The topic of threads can get really confusing as you move along .NET versions.

But to over-simplify, it depends on your processModel configuration for ASP.NET. (machine.config) **autoConfig=true/false** etc.

at a bare minimum, in .NET 4.0, the min/max WorkerThreads and min/max IOCompletionThreads determine the amount of threads in play.

e.g. If the minWorkerThreads = 1 (default value), then the total **minThreads = 1 * no:of cores**.. 
same with **maxWorkerThreads**.

Based on the load, the worker process can ramp up the threads needed to service the requests, using an undisclosed algorith.. minWorkerThreads to maxWorkerThreads. (of course based on availability of ThreadPool threads etc.)

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 8):

First, you have to consider that a web server is, by its nature, a multi-threaded system because it has to be able to respond to multiple requests at the same time (there are ways to do this in a single threaded environment, but it's not very efficient, and IIS does not support it).  If two users access the site at the same time, two separate threads are servicing each request in most cases.

Once you get into scalability issues, and async support, then a thread can actually service multiple requests (or rather, a request can be put on a queue and the IIS worker threads can be reused to process other requests).

So you are looking at this from the aspect of a single user.  And that single user will likely run only a single thread of activity during that web request (ignoring async, io completion ports, etc..).  i.e. you can think of a single web request as being equal to a single thread in the general sense (but there are so many things that can spin off other threads, that this isn't something that you can really count on).

When you use something like Parallel.ForEach it's so that your single users request can now execute things in multiple threads to improve efficiency.

An IIS web site has a worker process associated with it.  That worker process can be configured and tuned to control how many threads it uses.  But just remember, that your web site is running under the control of IIS, not as it's own application.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation, it is very helpful in understanding what is going on "under the hood" with IIS.